# Verilog conditional assignments without using procedural blocks like VHDL with/select

Tags: fpga, vhdl, verilog, hdl

I am trying to find a way to conditionally assign values to a signal in verilog similar to the with/select in VHDL. So far I found two ways https://www.chipverify.com/verilog/verilog-4to1-mux.

This is the first one:

```
module mux_4to1_assign ( input [3:0] a,                 // 4-bit input called a
                         input [3:0] b,                 // 4-bit input called b
                         input [3:0] c,                 // 4-bit input called c
                         input [3:0] d,                 // 4-bit input called d
                         input [1:0] sel,               // input sel used to select between a,b,c,d
                         output [3:0] out);             // 4-bit output based on input sel

   // When sel[1] is 0, (sel[0]? b:a) is selected and when sel[1] is 1, (sel[0] ? d:c) is taken
   // When sel[0] is 0, a is sent to output, else b and when sel[0] is 0, c is sent to output, else d
   assign out = sel[1] ? (sel[0] ? d : c) : (sel[0] ? b : a);

endmodule
```

Second one:

```
module mux_4to1_case ( input [3:0] a,                 // 4-bit input called a
                       input [3:0] b,                 // 4-bit input called b
                       input [3:0] c,                 // 4-bit input called c
                       input [3:0] d,                 // 4-bit input called d
                       input [1:0] sel,               // input sel used to select between a,b,c,d
                       output reg [3:0] out);         // 4-bit output based on input sel
                  
   // This always block gets executed whenever a/b/c/d/sel changes value
   // When that happens, based on value in sel, output is assigned to either a/b/c/d
   always @ (a or b or c or d or sel) begin
      case (sel)
         2'b00 : out <= a;
         2'b01 : out <= b;
         2'b10 : out <= c;
         2'b11 : out <= d;
      endcase
   end
endmodule
```

Both examples were taken from the link I shared before, my QUESTION IS if there is something in Verilog, similar to VHDL using the with/select, that is easy to understand without using procedural blocks?.

The first verilog example does the job but it takes a bit to understand the logic. Please keep in mind I am not complaining about or criticizing any language, I just want to know how to improve code readability for this particular case.

Comment: What do you mean by "better way"? Better readability? Optimized for speed/power/area?

Comment: @MituRaj, you got it, I meant better readability, I will try to edit my post. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want something based on an `assign` statement, your version can be improved:

```
// yours is below
assign out = sel[1] ? (sel[0] ? d : c) : (sel[0] ? b : a);

// but you can decode two bits at a time:
assign out = (sel==2'b00) ? a :
             (sel==2'b01) ? b :
             (sel==2'b10) ? c :
             (sel==2'b11) ? d :
             2'bx;  // should never hit this case, but you need an else
```

It's much more readable your version.  If you're not used to the ternary conditional operator, well you just have to get used to it.  It's part of C and many C-like languages (including Perl) but it's very widely used in Verilog since it's a natural multiplex operator, and it can be used in the middle of complex expressions.  Very helpful, and something I miss a lot now that I'm at a VHDL company.

Answer (score 4):

You can simplify the procedural block by using an implicit sensitivity list, `always @*` in Verilog and preferably `always_comb` in SystemVerilog. And you should not be using non-blocking assignments in combinational logic.

```
always_comb case (sel)
  2'b00 : out = a;
  2'b01 : out = b;
  2'b10 : out = c;
  2'b11 : out = d;
endcase
```

Almost the same amount of typing as the VHDL with/select.